# Domain for WordPress Database Repair using localhost

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have been playing around with WordPress recently and encountered my first

> “Error establishing Database Connection”.

I have done some research and posted this snippet into my wp-config.php file (right above 'That's all, stop editing ...):

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Now I need to go to http://your-site.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php in order to actually repair the database. But I'm running everything just locally.
My question therefore: with which '**domain**' do I replace "**your-site**" when just using a local host?

Thanks already a lot!

Comment: How did you access your WordPress site previously?

Comment: I'm using MAMP to access my database. I had it open and running yesterday and since my laptop shut down the error appears

Comment: What did you enter in addresss bar of your browser to see your WordPres site on laptop?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fwordpress%2F   when using the localhost:8888 as domain for the repair website i get an 404 error (The requested URL /wp-admin/maint/repair.php was not found on this server)

Comment: I do not ask how do you try to access /wp-admin. Did your WordPress site work previously? How did you access working site? What did you enter in browser to see pages of your site?

Comment: It worked within the localhost environment and I did only access it via wp-admin yesterday when working on it. It didn't have a specific domain yet so that I could access it through the browser outside of wp-admin – it was work in progress. Is there a way to see what you are asking for in the php files?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
localhost/wp-admin/maint/repair.php
```

But it depends on how your localhost is set up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. As it appears the suggested link leads me to an empty tab saying that it wasn't able to establish a connection to my local host. I have also tried localhost8888 and localhost8889